# Last logon mailbox status in Exchange

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I run the command Get-MailboxStatistics in Exchange Management Shell to check last logon time of users.

Here is command :

```
Get-MailboxStatistics -Identity username.ou
```

So for user no 1, powershell return warning something like this :

> The User Hasn’t Logged on to Mailbox So There is No Data to Return

So I guess this user never login to Exchange Mailbox

Then for user no 2, no warning is appear and I got the result but the LastLogonTime is NULL.

So I little bit confuse. What the different the user no 1 and 2? Can someone explain to me due I new in Exchange.

Comment: Could you show the command you're using?

Comment: Updated the question.